# use variable variable to get the section tab, and set it as a new variable using php

Tags: php, html, variables, tabs, dynamic-variables

I wanna ask if this code is possible to do.

```
$allowed_section = ['what', 'how', 'rules'];

if (isset($_GET['section']) && in_array($_GET['section']), $allowed_section) {
   $section = $_GET['section'];

} else {
   $$_GET['section'] = "what";
}
```

How can I declare the $$_GET['section'] value as $what or $how or $rules in HTML? Is it possible to do?

Example HTML:

```
<div class = "tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show  <?=($what)? "active" : ""; ?>" 
         id="what" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="what-tab"> ...  </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show  <?=($how)? "active" : ""; ?>" 
         id="how" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="how-tab"> ...  </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show  <?=($rules)? "active" : ""; ?>" 
         id="rules" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="rules-tab"> ...  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you must reverse your assignment.

```
$allowed_section = ['what', 'how', 'rules'];

if (isset($_GET['section']) && in_array($_GET['section'], $allowed_section)) {
    $$_GET['section'] = true;

} else {
    $section = $_GET['section'];
}
```